# Mapping list with function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I'm trying to change the position of a drawn path.

```
let redPath =  Path[Point 420 750, Point 420 550] red Solid

drawPicture 10 [redPath, movePictureObject (Vector 100 100)
redPath]
```

The functions movePictureObject and movePoint should change every point of the path with a given  vector (100,100).

```
movePoint :: Point -> Vector -> Point
movePoint (Point x y) (Vector xv yv)
  = Point (x + xv) (y + yv)

movePictureObject :: Vector -> PictureObject ->PictureObject
movePictureObject vec (Path points colour lineStyle) 
  = Path map (movePoint (points vec)) red Solid
```

I am not sure of how to use the map function properly, I have read several posts here and watched other tutorials.

Thank you.

Comment: What is `Path`? What is `Point`? What is a `PictureObject`? What is `Vector`? Why is this tagged [tag:dictionary]? And what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball tells me, that you just need `(map movePoint (points vec))` instead of `map (movePoint (points vec))` in the last line.

Comment: `(map (\p -> movePoint p vec) points)` seems more likely to me.

Comment: That did it @Daniel Wagner